# CL-JSON encodes Unicode chars by outputting their Unicode escape string in ASCII format. How can I override this?

Tags: json, unicode, common-lisp

I am using CL-JSON to encode an object. It spits the encoded string in ASCII format and the non-ASCII chars are written out as a sequence of ASCII chars in "\uxxxx" form. The result is that even if I open the output file stream with external format :utf-8, the file contains only ASCII chars. When I try to view it with for example notepad++ I cannot convert it to Unicode because now all the data is just ASCII (even the "\uXXXX" sequences). I would like either to know if there is an editor that will automatically convert the file to Unicode and recognize those escape sequences, or if there is a way to tell CL-JSON to keep the output characters in Unicode. Any ideas?

EDIT: here is some more info:

```
CL-USER>(with-open-file (out "dump.json" 
                          :direction :output 
                          :if-does-not-exist :create 
                          :if-exists :overwrite 
                          :external-format :utf-8)
             (json:encode-json '("abcd" "αβγδ") out) 
             (format out "~%"))

CL-USER>(quit)

bash$ file dump.json
dump.json: ASCII text
bash$ cat dump.json
["abcd","\u03B1\u03B2\u03B3\u03B4"]
bash$ uname -a
Linux suse-server 3.0.38-0.5-default #1 SMP Fri Aug 3 09:02:17 UTC 2012 (358029e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash$ sbcl --version
SBCL 1.0.50
bash$
```

EDIT2:

YASON does what I need, outputting chars without escaping them in \uXXXX format, but unfortunately it lacks features that I need, so it is not an option.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot be of any help -- the documentation of cl-json indeed does not mention unicode except for decode-issues with CMUCL.  However, would you mind, for reference, to post some minimal code, and mention the platform you are using?

Comment: I ve just added the info you requested

Comment: it looks the culprit for encoding is [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/darcs/cl-json/src/encoder.lisp) in `write-json-chars` there is a hard-coded check that a char be between #x1f and #x7f (32 & 127) otherwise the character is escaped. in [decoder.lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/darcs/cl-json/src/decoder.lisp) in `read-json-string-char` it appears that the escaping is undone, but no explicit range check is performed. You could try patching your copy of `write-json-chars` with a special variable to conditionally disable output escaping.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? `\u`-encoded characters are perfectly valid and will be turned into Unicode characters by any compliant JSON parser. Is it just increased human-readability you're going for?

Comment: @bobince Not only for readability, I  must do batch text processing stuff on it, I cant use a json parser, i dont need to parse the data, just to do text alterations in strings then hand it to someone else as json. I could do my stuff before converting it to json though, directly in lisp, but it is simpler to load it in a text editor and start regex replacements on it.

Comment: @lex yep i already did that (see my own answer) but I wonder if it could stand as a permanent solution. I dont know why they did it like that. Is it some kind mandatory standard?

Comment: @Paralife I don't know. looking [here](http://www.json.org/) it specifies 'Unicode' strings... perhaps this is just an artifact of interacting with c.l. implentations that don't support full utf-8? couldn't say.

Comment: Many JSON encoders escape non-ASCII in order to support non-Unicode-safe environments. Primarily that is browsers when a JavaScript interpreter is used to evaluate the JSON as script, In particular if you try to send UTF-8 as the response to a JSONP request, the originating page must also be in UTF-8. For JSONP services intended to be used by third parties who may be using all sorts of different encodings on their pages, making it ASCII-safe is a must. But yeah, good encoders allow you to turn that off if you don't need it.

Comment: In a dream world it would have obeyed the external-format key of the stream.   Failing that a optional argument on json:encode-json would seem to be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a temporary solution but I changed the CL-JSON source by redefining the appropriate function not to unicode-escape ranges outside ASCII. The function is named `write-json-chars` and it resides in file `encoder.lisp` in the sources.